# Use a single query on all databases

Tags: database, sqlite, sqlitestudio

I need to execute one simple query on a very large number of databases (50 to be precise) at the same time

`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 NOT IN(SELECT column1 FROM table2)`

I am using: 
SQLite Studio 3.1.0 
and .sqlite databases

SQLite doesn't allow the use of `DECLARE`, so I can't use variables to store all the DB names

Database name structure:
`commonpart_CUSTOM`

UPDATE:
I realised I didn't explain my query. I would like to select all content from `table1` where `column1` doesn't match values contained in `column1` from `table2`

I have to make this operation on 50 Databases all having the same structure but with different Data, instead of executing the query on one database at a time. I would like to be able to execute it on all my Databases with only one table for all the results merged but also declaring from which database it is coming from, though without having to write all the database names myself.

```
-Database1
  -Table1
     -Column1
     -Column2
     -Column3
     -Column4
  -Table2
     -Column1
     -Column2
     -Column3
  -Table3
     -Column1
     -Column2
     -Column3

-Database2
  -Table1
     -Column1
     -Column2
     -Column3
     -Column4
  -Table2
     -Column1
     -Column2
     -Column3
  -Table3
     -Column1
     -Column2
     -Column3
```

`Column1` from `table1`

 Contains data type declared in `Column1` from `table2` but in 1Million rows so it's duplicated

```
e.g.
row1 AAA
row2 AAA
row3 BBB
row4 FLM
```

`Column1` from `table2`

 Contains declared types of Data

 `e.g. Types: AAA, BBB, CCC, FFF`

Expected Output:

```
╔════╦══════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║    ║   Database   ║   Column1  ║   Column2  ║   Column3  ║  Column4   ║
╠════╬══════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║  1 ║ Database1    ║    FLM     ║Data        ║Data        ║Data        ║
║  2 ║ Database2    ║     -      ║Data        ║Data        ║Data        ║
║  3 ║ Database3    ║    NULL    ║Data        ║Data        ║Data        ║
║  4 ║ Database4    ║    NULL    ║Data        ║Data        ║Data        ║
╚════╩══════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

`Column1` from `Expected Output` contains all Data Types not matching with the ones defined in `Column1` from `table2`, The `Database` Column contains the name of the database from which the output is coming from, the other columns containg all the other that of the row where the not matching value was found

Since `Column1` from `table1` on row4 contains FLM which is not present in `Column1` from `table2` it is expected as output

I just need a way to tell my query to execute on multiple databases without writing the names of the databases myself, just like a loop.

NOTE: I am only able to provide Generic Data because it's work related, sorry.

Comment: Perhaps you can use SQLite `attach database` statement? https://sqlite.org/lang_attach.html

Comment: @Arvo Using attach database is a solution, but I would have to write all the database names myself, I want to still be able to use the query in case my database names change. That means generic/parametrized

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way of accessing data in different databases is to [ATTACH](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) them.
The default [limit for attached databases](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_attached) is 10, so you have to compile your own version of the SQLite library in order to increase this limit.
Once you have that, you can use a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) over all fifty tables:

```
ATTACH '...' as db1;
ATTACH '...' as db2;
...

SELECT 'Database1' AS DB, * FROM db1.Table1 WHERE Column1 NOT IN (SELECT Column1 FROM db1.Table2)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Database2'      , * FROM db2.Table1 WHERE Column1 NOT IN (SELECT Column1 FROM db2.Table2)
UNION ALL
...
```

SQLite is an embedded database and designed to be used from a 'real' programming language. Therefore, it is not possible to construct SQL statements dynamically from within SQL itself. Instead, you have to construct the query in your program.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a specific answer not knowing the schema you're working with, but one thing you could try is using a view:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_views.htm

Comment: I would like to avoid to write everything manually, but to use something automated instead, in case I want to use the same trick with other databases or a different amount.
Also, if you could explain to me what do you mean by schema I could give you more information.